# How to access each element returned by first-child selector

Tags: jquery

Assuming the following selector

```
$("div span:first-child")
```

applied in following html code

John,
        Karl,
        Brandon

```
   </div>
   <div>
    <span>Glen,</span>
    <span>Tane,</span>
    <span>Ralph</span>
  </div>
```

> [as seen on jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

is there a way to reference "each" element returned?

I can't seem to be able to iterate through them using *.each()* (*.size()* returns 0)

**Update:** you are right there is something different which I missed for some reason but didn't occur to me that this might be an issue while reading the documentation.

So it seems that *first-child* selector returns only if the element is actually **the** first child and not just the first occurrence.

e.g.

```
   <div>
    <h1>Names</h1>
    <span>John,</span>
    <span>Karl,</span>
    <span>Brandon</span>    
   </div>
   <div>
    <span>Glen,</span>
    <span>Tane,</span>
    <span>Ralph</span>
  </div>
```

will return only the span from the 2nd div.

Is that a "feature"? Is there an alternative way to select the first child? (based on occurrence)

Comment: both `.size()` and `.length` return **2** for me. Do you call your code within `.ready()` ?

Comment: .size() returns .the length ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated for new question:* This finds the first span in each `<div>`, regardless if it's actually *the* first child.

```
$("div").find("span:first").each(function() {
    alert("This is child #" + $(this).index() + " in this section: " + $(this).text());
});​
```

[You can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nWxDL/1/).

---

You can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to do what you want, like this:

```
$("div span:first-child")​.each(function() {
  alert("This is child #" + $(this).index() + " in this section: " + $(this).text());
});​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nWxDL/).

For this:

> I can't seem to be able to iterate through them using .each() (.size() returns 0)

There *must* be something outside the code you posted, running on that markup does work, as you can see in my demo.  You need to see what's different about your actual markup that...that difference is likely what's causing the issue.

Comment: you are right Nick, there is something more which I clearly missed. Please see my update. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The title of my question looks all irrelevant now though :).
So it seems that the doc for :first-child is misleading.

"While :first matches only a single element, the :first-child selector can match more than one: one for each parent."

Since :first-child requires that the child is actually the first element compared to :first

Comment: @Cue -There's a selector for that! [:first-of-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo) But...it's just a CSS3 selector at the moment, [one jQuery doesn't support in core](http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#Not_supported) (it does work in a selector if the *browser* supports it).

Answer (score 3):

```
$("div span:first-child").each(function(){
           alert($(this).text());}
     );
```

[Demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/uhrta/1/)

Alternatively,

```
var spans=$("div span:first-child");
$.each(spans, function(index, sp) {
alert(index + ' - ' +$(sp).text());
});
```

[Demo2](http://www.jsfiddle.net/5dFTc/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the first matching span in all div's

[​`$("div").find("span:first")`](http://jsfiddle.net/bVqXX/)

These variations should work as well:

```
span:lt(1)
span:eq(0)
span:not(:gt(0)) // speaking of efficiency :)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span:first-child > div").text('Whooo')
```

Method 2 if the div has id

```
$("span:first-child > #divID");
```

each.

```
$("span:first-child > div").each(function(){
   $(this).doSomethig();
})
```

--

Test Case::

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google AJAX Search API Sample</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAA1XbMiDxx_BTCY2_FkPh06RRaGTYH6UMl8mADNa0YKuWNNa8VNxQEerTAUcfkyrr6OwBovxn7TDAH5Q"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("jquery", "1");

      function OnLoad()
      {
        jQuery("div > span:first-child").each(function(){
          console ? console.log(this) : alert(typeof this); //Logs the element
        });
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div>
    <span>John,</span>
    <span>Karl,</span>
    <span>Brandon</span>

   </div>
   <div>
    <span>Glen,</span>
    <span>Tane,</span>
    <span>Ralph</span>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"span:first-child > div"` has to be `"div span:first-child"`

Comment: yes sorry your correct, I was meaning to do `div > spac:first-child`.